# Slow edit updates on Stack Overflow after recent updates

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits

Is it just me or are other people also experiencing an edit lag issue on Stack Overflow?

I was posting an answer on Stack Overflow and then made a few edits to my answer. To my amazement, after submitting the edit, it was still showing me my un-edited answer.

Comment: Yes, experienced the exact same thing but since I'm new here I guessed it might be due to some pending review or something...but that entirely goes down "asynchronously" right? :D

Comment: I noticed the same a couple of days ago, can't remember if it was here on Meta or on SO. A page refresh fixed it.

Comment: yeah a page indeed fixed it but I guess SO should look after this

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you post what OS and Browser you are using (and versions)?

Comment: @Oded OS - Windows 8 and latest version of chrome - it seems that - that was for that particular time only